# What happens when Grails BuildConfig scope doesn't specify organization?

Tags: maven, grails, ivy, buildconfig

In a Grails app's `BuildConfig.groovy` you can specify repos to find dependencies/plugins in:

```
repositories {
    mavenRepo: "http://path/to/my/repo"
}

plugins {
    compile: "fizz:buzz:0.4.3"
}
```

In the above example, Grails will look for a `buzz-0.4.3.zip` plugin located in the repo mentioned above that. It's "organization" segment is `fizz`, which is the name of the organization that authored the `buzz-0.4.3.zip`.

But all the time I see `compile` scopes written like so:

```
compile: ":buzz:0.4.3"
```

I scoured the [`BuildConfig` documentation](http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/conf.html), but can't seem to find where they explain what happens when this "organization" segment is missing in the scope.

So I ask: what does it mean when one doesn't specify organization? Is there a default that is applied? When is it appropriate *not* to use organization?

Comment: There's definitely a default applied to _plugin_ dependencies

Comment: Thanks @IanRoberts (+1) - good catch I meant to put `plugins` and not `dependencies`, please see update. Thoughts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the documentation (section [4.7.11 - plugin dependencies](http://grails.org/doc/2.3.7/guide/conf.html#pluginDependencies))

> If you don't specify a group id the default plugin group id of `org.grails.plugins` is used.

("group ID" being the Maven terminology for what you've called the "organization").  All the standard plugins listed at https://grails.org/plugins/ use the default group ID.